# Ubuntu live CD keeps on going back to the choice screen

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, windows, livecd

I had Ubuntu installed before, but then I decided to switch to Windows 7. I deleted all of the partitions and formatted the drive (via the Windows installation disk). Windows works fine, but now I want to reinstall Ubuntu.

When I boot via the livecd, it gives me the options screen, "try Ubuntu without installing", "install Ubuntu" etc. Whenever I try the "try Ubuntu without installing", "install Ubuntu" options, it goes to the Ubuntu loading screen for a bit, then sends me right back to that same decision screen. If I select the last option, "check CD for errors", just goes through what I assume is a check, and then sends me to a screen that says, "press any key to continue". Once I press a key, it sends me back to the decision screen.

I've tried using different install disks and re-downloading the ISO (from the torrent file they have on their website and the direct download option). I've even tried Ubuntu Gnome just in case. Same deal. What can I do?

I'm assuming it has something to do with the Windows format that I did. Maybe the format wasn't very thorough, and Ubuntu is picking up some remnant information it doesn't know what to do with?

Comment: Using the Windows 7 CD, I formatted the hard drive and deleted all of the partitions. I made 10 GB and 90 GB partitions (in addition to the automatically created 100 MB partition). Then I restarted the computer using the Ubuntu Live CD. I clicked both options and it still does not work.

Comment: An old 32 bit Ubuntu 13 point something CD loads!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226719, on Ubuntuforums.org.

Comment: That's a fairly multi-page forum thread. It'd make your answer much more useful if you were to summarize the useful portions of that thread in your answer.